# How to call .dll file by URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I don't know it is silly question or not but can i call the `.dll` file hosted in IIS from URL with parameters.

For eg. `https://<ipaddress>/createuser.dll?`(User variable from the client application like name, email, address)

If yes then how to do that.

I google a lot but no desired result.

Comment: i think you need to use HttpHandler for this...

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting the entry point in the DLL to be? And what do you expect back from the DLL. This sounds like more of a remote procedure call that you're after, in which case you probably want to look into WCF when combined with http channels.

Comment: For eg. i have .dll file in server and separate asp.net web application with user form when the user click submit button it calls the .dll file with all the user data. By given the reference of dll it is possible but the client requirement is what i said earlier

Comment: If you've got some code in a DLL on a web server that you want executed as a result of a client call I'd be looking at some sort of web interface on the front of it - eg put a web api in front of it. That will cope with the request from the client and call the desired code in the DLL. If you want to avoid that, you could probably craft a HttpHandler, like @VishalPrajapati suggested, but that would be much harder I think.

Comment: thanks @IanofOz  There should not be any mediator between the cleint app and .dll files. Client must call dll files directly. And yeah httphandler option is more complex and time consuming.

Comment: Why no mediator? If you were to go down the path of a httphandler, that's a mediator. Basically I don't believe there's any way to do what you want without some mediation.

Comment: Actually, you say you have an asp.net web application? Why doesn't that just reference the DLL and the submit button handler call your createuser DLL?

Comment: Thanks @IanofOz for your guide. Me too think there is no such option. That is why i mentioned a silly question.

Comment: @IanofOz I did that it is working properly but they are not agree for that process.

Comment: OK, I'd say you can either say it's not possible, or look at WCF. Good luck...

Comment: Yes. Thank you again :)